# Why isnt this simple inheritance working?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I'm trying to use the properties object parameter in Object.create, the mdn says you pass an object into it, but when I pass an object into it I get an error telling me to passing an object, I'm confused as to what I'm doing wrong

```
let mammal={hasFur:true}

let dog=Object.create(mammal,{legs:4});//returns Uncaught TypeError: Property description must be an object: true at Function.create (<anonymous>)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've described `legs` as `4`, and `4` is not an object.

See [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) which includes examples of the sorts of things you can assign there:

> ```
> o = Object.create(Object.prototype, {
>   // foo is a regular 'value property'
>   foo: {
>     writable: true,
>     configurable: true,
>     value: 'hello'
>   },
> ```

In this example we use `foo` instead of `legs`. The value of an object, which includes a `value` property holding the default value for `foo`.

Answer (score 2):

In a simple definition, [Object.create(proto[, propertiesObject])](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) is a mean for defining the abstract for object's properties, or defining specification of object's properties. It works like `abstract classes` in some of the other languages, & not a `specific object`.

It is not there to necessarily provide a default value for the props of the object being created.
You have provided a literal (4) only, which is obviously not an object having the ability to describe specification for the property. We will see here, that 4 in its own is(even not necessarily) only a part of properties object for legs.

Now. with this in mind lets try to create your `dog` object using `Object.create()`. Here we go:

- **Requirements:** we want our dog to have a property named `legs`.
- **design:** we need `legs` to be enumerable while enumerating the object.  we don't want to let others to change it with assignment operator. & also we want to default to 4.
- **Implementation:** Now that we've decided on specification of `legs` property, we need a [Property Descriptor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) to define it.[the second parameter of `Object.defineProperties(obj, props)`]

The `props` mentioned above is second{& optional} parameter in `Object.create(proto[, propertiesObject])` & has some keys for describing properties of objects:

```
props {configurable, enumerable, value, writable, get, set}
```

Lets code the `dog` object:

```
let dog=Object.create(mammal,{
                      legs:{
                          enumerable : true,
                          writable : false,
                          value : 4 }
                     });
```

For more clarification, reading both of the references linked above, is highly helpful.